# Stability of dynamical system via Lyapunov

Tags: stability

I have a dynamical system which has the following form:
$\dot x=\mathcal F_1(m_1)x+\mathcal F_2(m_2)x$.
My objective is to find the parameters $m_1$ and $m_2$ via LMI (linear matrix inequality)  using the Lyapunov function $V=x^TPx$ where $x$ is the state and $P$ is a  positive definite matrix. The problem that I can't find a feasible solution with a single matrix $P$. I tried to solve the problem with tow steps:

1. I consider that $\dot x=\mathcal F_1(m_1)x+\omega_1$ then using the Lyapunov function 
   $V_1=x^TP_1x$ (of course using the mathematical background) I can find the first parameter $m_1$;
2. I consider that $\dot x=\mathcal F_2(m_2)x+\omega_2$ and as in the first step I can find the second parameter $m_2$ using the Lyapunov function $V_2=x^TP_2x$ and using them in the simulation they work very well.

My questions are about:

1. $m_1$ and $m_2$ were found independently how can I guarantee
   the stability of the system using $m_1$ and $m_2$ in other words how can I prove the stability of the system?
2. It is well known that the Lyapunov function is also so called the energy of the system so can I say that $V=\frac{1}{2}(V_1+V_2)$ is also the energy of the system?

Comment: So $\mathcal F_1(m_1)+\mathcal F_2(m_2)$ is just a matrix? If so can't you just check stability by looking at the eigenvalues of this sum?

Comment: yes, is just matrix, but the solution must be done according to Lyapunov theory (many other methods are already used and it works)  
thank you for your intention

Comment: If the sum is Hurwitz then you can always find a $P$ by solving the Lyapunov equation with for example $Q$ the identity matrix.

Comment: to fine the solution with respect to lyapunov we take the derivative of the function $V$ and we search the solution $P, m_1, m_2$  that guarentee $V<0$